# iOS- instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier with out navigationBar

Tags: ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i have a navigation controller with navigation bar define in it.
i want to use with that method:

```
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier
```

without the navigationBar (just for specific screen, for all the rest i want the navigationBar).

can someone help me?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After instantiate your viewController call

```
[controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

as the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setNavigationBarHidden%3aanimated%3a) of the `UINavigationController` class states:

> You can hide and show the navigation bar using the `navigationBarHidden` property or `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` method.